# MongoDB, PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have the following document in a MongoDB 2.0.4 and PHP 5.5*

```
{
    "children" : [
            {
                    "name" : "openGL::gl"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "openGL::interfaces"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "openGL::picking"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "openGL::objects"
            }
    ],
    "name" : "test"
}
```

Using php I want to create another collection having a copy of this document.Because I cannot use php mongo::command I am just getting a cursor for the first collection and insert this cursor into the second:

```
    $cursor = $collection->find();
    foreach($cursor as $document){
        $result->insert($document);
    };
```

$collection is the original and $result is the new one.
Now the strange thing is sometimes this works perfectly and sometimes I recieve the following:

```
{
    "children" : {
            "3" : {
                    "name" : "openGL::objects"
            },
            "0" : {
                    "name" : "openGL::gl"
            },
            "1" : {
                    "name" : "openGL::interfaces"
            },
            "2" : {
                    "name" : "openGL::picking"
            }
    },
    "name" : "test"
}
```

And this is really bad because I am trying to get those infos into Javascript and therefore the first one (the original) is an Array whereas the second one is an object with properties.
Does somebody know why I get this and how to fix it?

So this is the solution I am using now!

```
    $db->command(array(
        "eval" => new MongoCode("function(){
            db['".$toCopy."'].copyTo('".$newName."')
        };"
        )
    ));
```

Comment: thanks those were just suggestions by stackoverflow although I have JS in my topic xD

Comment: Is this straight off the [PHP MongoDB driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.core.php) or using something else ?

Comment: the two examples are dirrectly from commandline and the php code is using nothing special so I guess it will be the PHP MongoDB driver

Comment: Seems a worry. I would check driver version. Also Mongo is quite old 2.0.4. Do you have the [db.cloneCollection()](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/) method available from the shell? Or is this a sharded cluster?

Comment: I try to update Mongo tomorrow but I cannot to this via shell I have to clone with PHP.

Comment: Not understanding. Why should you not be able to connect with the shell. Also that method and another are server interactions. Using your PHP driver you are pulling all documents over the network and writing them back over the network.

Comment: So what exactly would you do please provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy a collection on the server with the [`.copyTo()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) method for the collection:

```js
db.collection.copyTo("new")
```

There is no client transfer as there is currently being done by iterating.

If for some reason you want this to be a part of your code then there is the ["runCommand"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php) option which has a longer syntax. So in PHP code, do the longer version of this with "eval":

```
$db->command(array(
   "eval" => new MongoCode("function(){ " .
       "db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { " .
           "db.newcollection.insert(doc); " .
       "}); " .
     "};"
   );
));
```

That will run the copy on the server. Take care to read the documentation and warnings on [`db.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/). And aside from all else, but much the same as you were doing, then you must re-create all indexes on the target collection that you want to use.

But in general this will be a better way than iterating over a client connection.

Comment: ah I see but I have to do it from a Controller (PHP)

Comment: @d3orn So your code needs to do this regularly? Or is this just a one off operation?

Comment: Regularly, basicly I have the original collection and every time something happens I create a copy of it do some stuff and then delete the copy

Comment: @d3orn Okay. Have added a way to execute this from your PHP code. Make sure to check those driver and server updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this ASAP and write back

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to sort the cursor like:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor = $cursor->sort(array('name_of_key_variable' => 1)); //sorts in ascending order
foreach($cursor as $doc) {
    ...
}
```

You might also try more of the MongoCursor options listed here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php at the table of contents

Comment: Why would I want to sort the cursor it should not even have an order because it should not have "0" : something it should just be the same as the original

Comment: Neil's answer is probably best in terms of performance, etc. but couldn't you ensure an index via:  // create an index on 'name' ascending
$collection->ensureIndex(array('name' => 1)); and manipulate from there...